# How to use download url from meteor slingshot

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback

I am using meteor slingshot for uploading image to amazon s3. This is the function I am using to upoad image file.

```
_handleMainImageUpload() {
    const mainPictureFile = $("#vendorMainPicture")[0].files[0];
    const upload = new Slingshot.Upload("myImageUploads");
    upload.send(mainPictureFile, function (error, downloadUrl) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('uploaded file available here: ' + downloadUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

I need to use `downloadUrl` in some other function. How can I return `downloadUrl` to other function?

Comment: Call the function and pass downloadUrl as a parameter: someOtherFunction(downloadUrl)

Comment: Ok Got it, Thanks